# Why did Hendricks jump from the parking structure at the end of the fight scene in MI4?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-ghost-protocol

In [Mission:Impossible-Ghost Protocol](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229238/), at the last fight scene, Ethan and Hendricks were in a parking structure and Ethan was trying to get that briefcase which contains the Satellite launch terminal.

In the end of the fight scene, Hendricks jumps from the middle of the building and dies. But it surprised me because he was a **nuclear strategist**, why did he die like that? As a **sane man** he might have known, if he jumped from the middle of the building he would definitely be killed and obviously Ethan will get the briefcase and press the abort button.

Can someone explain to me **why Hendricks jumped from the parking structure at the end of the fight scene in MI4?**

Answer (score 7):

It has everything to do with him being a good thinker. well he knew ethan couldn't move all the way from the top of the car factory to the bottom with that injured leg (quite sure he gets injured while they fight i think it was the leg).

Here is my take on this. Since the time to launch was closeby he assumed with the injury it will take more time for Ethan to reach his deadbody if he take the fall and ethan takes the regular route to get to him. He assumed even if Ethan followed suit and jumped  then Ethan would end up being dead like him so it makes it win-win scenario even in his death and quite possibly assumed that none of the cars in the factory were in a driveable state because you see parts of cars being assembled while they were assembled and you hardly expect those cars to have fuel as well in the factory when being assembled.

So there you go!

Comment: It wasn't a factory.  It was an [automated parking garage](http://www.drivelineblog.com/2006/05/16/vws-robotic-car-garage/).

Comment: Although it was a parking lot and not a factory, I guess Hendricks just did not think of the possibility to ride a car to the bottom, so the rest of the answer still applies. Of course eradication of most mankind from earth and making a new beginning is a most noble reason to die for.

Comment: Alas, the link in my previous comment broke, but here's another link to the same [automated parking garage](http://www.designboom.com/technology/volkswagen-parking-lot-towers-at-autostadt/).

Comment: He could've just thrown the suitcase. Why jump with it?

Answer (score 3):

He didn't plan to survive the nuclear holocaust, if my memory serves me correctly. So it kind of makes sense for him to act like a suicide bomber would. The problem here really is that sacrificing himself at this point is counterproductive to his goals. His plan is to prevent Hunt from pressing abort. A better way to do this is throw down the briefcase and continue fighting Hunt to the death at the platform, maybe try to pull Hunt down with him. This would buy him even more time to complete his evil scheme.

Nevertheless, it was badass of him to just take the case and make the jump no matter what. Serves to show just how comitted he is to his whole eradication-of-the-human-race-plan. So it was an understandable decision from a director's point of view.