# Ending of Mission Impossible 4

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-ghost-protocol

In the last act of [*Mission Impossible - Ghost Protocol*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229238/) *Hendricks* was still alive and was watching *Ethan* trying to deactivate the bomb and yet does nothing and breathed his last breath once it's deactivated. Why is it so? What does this mean?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2488/49. While it isn't really a duplicate, it might provide some additional insights.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure he actually was able to do anything else than just lie around. If I remember correctly he fell from a huge height (or rather jumped off himself in order to nobly sacrifice himself for the cause), in order to make the detonator (or whatever it was in particular) unreachable from *Ethan* for the few seconds that remained.

So I'm sure he wasn't able to move and was already near to death. The will to see his plan succeed was keeping him alive, but once *Ethan* crushed this plan (*Hendricks* surely didn't anticipate *Ethan*'s reckless maneuvre with the car) he had no reason to stay alive anymore.

Comment: Had watched it long time back, thought they both jumped together, so was wondering how could Ehtan move but Hendricks coudlnt.

Comment: @2-Stroker *Ethan* rode (or rather flew) a car down to the bottom to use its crash-safety features to his advantage (though that was still not that dangerless a maneuvre, but in the end it's *Ethan Hunt* ;)).